# What is the $\lim_{x\to \infty} $ ${\left({\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{x} + {\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{3x}\right)}^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

${\left({\frac{1}{2}}^{x} + {\frac{1}{2}}^{3x}\right)}^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$
I tried to simplified the equation into
${\frac{2^x + 2^{3x}}{2^{4x}}}^{1/x^2}$

I applied $ln$ to both sides

Then using L'hotpital

But i don't think it is the best way, because this question supposed to be done in few minutes.

Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2} = 0$.

Comment: ...oh... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

Your function can be written as

$$\Bigl(2^{-x}(1+2^{-2x}\Bigr)^\frac{1}{x^2}=$$
$$2^{\frac{-1}{x}}(1+2^{-2x})^\frac{1}{x^2}$$

The limit is $2^0(1+0)^0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to this question is realizing that the expression is being raised to $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$.
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=0$$
Anything to the zero power is one.

I noticed that Duncan already posted this. However, in your steps you said that you applied L'Hospital's rule. This will not get you the answer that you want, even if you did it correctly. This is because L'Hospital's rule only applies to fractions in an indeterminate form ($\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$) after direct substitution, for example (disregarding that $\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}}=1$)$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{3x^2}{x^2}\right)$$ would apply to L'Hospital's rule because after DS the fraction is the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: .... Oh..... thanks...

Answer (score 0):

As $x\to+\infty$:
\begin{align}
\log\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}
&=\frac{1}{x^2}\log(2^{-x} + 2^{-3x})\\
&=\frac{1}{x^2}\log(2^{-x}(1+2^{-2x}))\\
&=-\frac{1}{x}\log(2)+\frac{1}{x^2}\log(1+2^{-2x})\\
&\to 0
\end{align}
because
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2}\log(1+2^{-2x})
&\sim\frac1{x^22^{2x}}\\
&\to 0
\end{align}

Comment: What do you mean by 
because
$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2}\log(1+2^{-2x})
&\sim\frac1{x2^{2x}}\\
&\to 0
\end{align}$

Comment: @Lifeforbetter See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis)

Comment: $
\frac{1}{x^2}\log(1+2^{-2x}) =  0/0$ it is undefined?

Comment: Note that $x\to+\infty$

Comment: $\frac{1}{\infty^2}\log(1+2^{-2\infty}) = 0/0$ ?

Comment: No, it's $0/\infty$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\infty^2} = 0, \log(1+2^{-2 \infty}) = \log(1 + 0) = 0$ so, $0 . 0$

Comment: Then it is $0\cdot 0$

Comment: but other's answers are 1

Comment: Because $\log(1)=0$

Comment: Oh.. i see ok then

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\underbrace{\left( \frac 12\right)^{\frac 1x}}_{\stackrel{x\to \infty}{\rightarrow}1} \leq \left( \left( \frac 12 \right)^x + \left( \frac 12 \right)^{3x} \right)^{\frac 1{x^2}}\leq \left(2 \left( \frac 12 \right)^x \right)^{\frac 1{x^2}} = \underbrace{2^{\frac 1{x^2}}\cdot \left( \frac 12 \right)^{\frac 1x}}_{\stackrel{x\to \infty}{\rightarrow}1} $$